# javascriptで配列を返す

Tags: javascript

```js
var hoge = [];
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  hoge.push(i);
};

var getHoge = function(){
  return hoge;
};

var fuga = getHoge;
alert(hoge);
alert(fuga);
```

配列を取得したいので上のようなコードを書いたのですが､配列が返ってきませんでした｡  どう修正すれば配列を取得できますか?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var hoge = [];
for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
  hoge.push(i);
};

var getHoge = function(){
  return hoge;
};

var fuga = getHoge();
alert(hoge);
alert(fuga);
```

Comment: ありがとうございます｡
()を付けないとその関数自体が文字列で返ってきて､
つけるとその返り値が返ってくるのですか｡勉強になりました｡

Comment: @zousan 文字列で返ってくるわけではなく、関数そのものが代入されます。`alert`で表示するときに文字列に変換されているだけです。